# video streaming serialization

Tags: c++, video, serialization, streaming

I am working on a video streaming application in C++, and I have questions about serialization of the packets. I know there are a number of serialization frameworks out there from Google Protocol Buffers, Apache Thrift, Cereal, etc. I am correct in thinking that the packets will need to be serialized, right?

Since any little bit of overhead can cause latency, is it worthwhile to use an existing framework to do the serialization?

Would it even be worth my time to try and roll my own or just stick to the frameworks?

I know most of the frameworks will take into account big-endian and little-endian which is nice.

From the research I have done, I was leaning towards trying to use Google Protocol Buffers. Is this a good serialization library for a streaming application?

Are there any other suggestions?

I appreciate the advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The framework should help you send and retrieve *packets*.  Filling in the packet with a payload is your task.

If you are worried about the latency and don't want to delay your processing by waiting for packets to be sent, you should consider using a separate thread and buffer for the packets.

For example, the processing thread would create or fill in a packet and put it into the outgoing buffer (e.g. circular queue).  The packet sending thread would take packets from the buffer and send them out.  The thread would sleep until either the packet has been sent or a new packet is added to the queue.

This technique will "blast" the network with packets, which you may not want to do.  If you continuously blast packets, nobody else will be able to send out packets.  This may not be a problem depend on routers and switches on the network and your packet framework.

Comment: Well I was trying to stay away from buffers on the sender, since it's a video streaming application. But it seems to be unavoidable. Would you recommend protocol buffers then?